# Hibernate import.sql with PostgreSQL repeats primary keys

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I am using Hibernate with PostgreSQL. I have an import.sql file that Hibernate executes after the schema is created/validated. The content is imported accordingly, but when I try to persist new entries through my application, Hibernate tries to use automatically generated primary keys starting from 1, which were already used by my import file. Is there  way to fix this?

I have a single entity class that all other entities inherit from, which uses either `GenerationType.AUTO` or `GenerationType.IDENTITY`. Both of them did not work:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Entidade implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -991512134416936719L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    public Entidade() {
    }

    public Entidade(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

And here is my persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="...">
        <jta-data-source>...</jta-data-source>
        <class>...</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
            <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="jcat" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor"
                value="org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files" value="import.sql" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="3000" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="1800" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: why not look at the SQL invoked for the INSERT?

Comment: You need to change your SQL script so that the sequences are adjusted inside the script. But without seeing that script this is impossible to give more details (basically you shouldn't be using hard-coded IDs in there, but obtain  the IDs from the sequences)

Comment: And what if I have foreign keys that need to be filled? With hard-coded IDs, I know exactly which IDs to put, but by using sequences, I can't know for sure which values are being used by the sequence so that I can put them in the foreign keys.

Comment: You don't need to. Simply reference the generated IDs using e.g. `lastval()` or use data modifying CTEs. Show us your SQL script. There are loads of examples for that on StackOverflow.

Comment: The definition of JPA "IDENTITY" is a generated value that is set __in the datastore__. This is intended for AUTO_INCREMENT/SERIAL type features in RDBMS. By the fact that you have used an INT you have subverted the JPA mechanism. aka user error

Comment: But on databases like MySQL and MariaDB, the exact same variable with this annotation and data type creates an autoincrement column that doesn't force the developer to explicitly use database sequences. I wonder what's the correct variable type I should have used to create an autoincrement column if not int or long.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am currently trying to solve my problem with sequences, like you suggested. Either if I succeed or fail, I'll post my progress and my script soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, Hibernate uses a global database-wide sequence called `hibernate_sequence`. You can import it form an other database too. You can add to your script an `insert` statement for a large id value in `hibernate_sequence`.

Please, see in the SQL log does Hibernate use `hibernate_sequence`?

**Update**
Some additional notes by @DouglasDeRizzoMeneghetti

> I did as you said and it worked. The FKs became integers, which are nullable, and now I have only one sequence in the database, instead of one for each ID. I found out that even join tables had their own sequences created, so by using a single sequence, everything got cleaner and more organized.

Comment: If you use GenerationType.SEQUENCE, Hibernate does create its own sequence, but the values are used across all tables, and that is a behavior I'd like to avoid.

Comment: @DouglasDeRizzoMeneghetti Don't know a reason why you do so. Our team have been using such sequences for really large systems for a lot of years (with Oracle DB and PostgreSQL). But as you wish :)

Answer (score 2):

It turns out PostgreSQL has a "serial" data type for its columns, which is basically an integer data type associated with a sequence. the sequence is automatically created and handled by the DBMS. In order to force Hibernate to create such a column type, one uses the `@Column(columnDefinition = "serial")` annotation, like so:

```
@Id
@Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
```

Note that, while a sequence is being used to generate IDs, I didn't use `strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE`, because that would tell Hibernate to create is own `hibernate_sequence` and use it across all tables, a behavior I tried to avoid. The name of the generated sequence follows the pattern `${tablename}_${column_id_name}_seq`, like 'client_id_seq'. I could then omit in my import script the hard-coded insertion of IDs, so:

```
insert into schema.table (id, name) values (1, 'John');
```

became:

```
insert into schema.table (name) values ('John');
```

and, when persisting entities in my webapp, Hibernate automatically uses the correct sequence for each table, so I did not have any more problems regarding repeated values.

As another contribution, if you have a `@MappedSuperclass` that uses the aforementioned annotation in its ID column, all subclasses automatically create their own sequences, so it's not necessary to do it for every single entity. The only down side I saw is that, while I had an annotation that worked under MariaDB but not PostgreSQL, now I have an annotation that would not work on MariaDB, since I don't recall it having the serial data type that `@Column(columnDefinition = "serial")` forces. So much for abstraction and detachment from the database.

**EDIT:** This strategy raised another problem. The fact that my PKs were of serial type made Hibernate create their corresponding FKs as serial. Since the serial type can't be nullablein PostgreSQL, I couldn't have optional relations between my entities. I ended up using the solution proposed by @v.ladynev, using `GenerationType.SEQUENCE` in my entities IDs and setting a high starting value for `hibernate_sequence`, after inserting my test data

This way, the FKs became integers, which are nullable, and now I have only one sequence in the database, instead of one for each ID. I found out that even join tables had their own sequences created, so by using a single sequence, everything got cleaner and more organized. Thank you.

Comment: How do you deal with foreign keys?

Comment: In the import script, I can just use the sequential numbers I used before. However, PostgreSQL creates FK columns as `serial` columns and also creates their corresponding sequences, but the `serial` column also allows you to choose a value during data insertion, in which case it does not use the sequence value. As of now, I have not observed any problems.

Comment: @v.ladynev now I think I know what you were talking about. Since my foreign keys are of serial type, they can't be nullable, so I can't have have optional relations between my entities. Now that's a problem I'll need help with.

Comment: So why don't return to the sequence approach?

Comment: @v.ladynev You mean using `hibernate_sequence`? Then my columns can be of plain old integer type?

Comment: Yes. You will need to insert a large value in the `hibernate_sequence`.

Comment: I did as you said and it worked. The FKs became integers, which are nullable, and now I have only one sequence in the database, instead of one for each ID. I found out that even join tables had their own sequences created, so by using a single sequence, everything got cleaner and more organized. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

data type of your id column in postgres should be serial

than use this annotation

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

Comment: Currently my PKs are of type int. If that's the case, then how do I set the serial column type by annotating my class?

Comment: you need to change your column datatype in PostgreSQL database, you can't change type of column by annotating class.

Comment: `@Id @Column(columnDefinition = "serial") @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` does the trick.